# dj_rest_auth restrict user registration to a certaing group

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

Based on [Django REST framework: Check user is in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372553/django-rest-framework-check-user-is-in-group) , I have succesfully restricted my custom views to certain groups.

Yet, I need to restrict dj_rest_auth.views.RegisterView to a certain group.

How can I make it?

I thought of trying to set a wrapper class over RegisterView, and link my wrapper class in `urls.py`, but what methods should I override?

Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems dj-rest-auth is ready for this need:

```
#settings.py
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_PERMISSION_CLASSES = ("rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated","api.permissions.HasLoginPermission")
```

Keep in mind there's a bug in dj-rest-auth<1.1.12 that prevents those string to work.